# Basic question about MS SQL Server Management Studio regarding column specification

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is about Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

**Preface**
My PC went kaput (GPU or Motherboard buses are to blame, as far as I can tell from the long beep followed by 3 short ones: Asus beep code for "no VGA found" (sabretooth X79 or something... it doesn't really concern my question). Since that happened, I've got cut off from the other good PC in the house. I am currently using an amateurish PC owned by people in my family who don't need to code or anything like that.

**Question**
All of the backstory (and I suspect more than necessary) being now clear. I'd like to quickly go over the problem: I've installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio in this computer which isn't mine. I was never any good with SQL (the Standard makes a lot of sense - but I'm quite rusty at it, problem are its implementations and GUIs -> APIs e.g. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it).

**tl;dr**
Is there a way to visually add a default to a column? (columns I create have identifier (column name), Type, and AllowNull as the only configurable bits of info I'm allowed to change.

Using these:

```
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18338.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)                 16.100.41011.9
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools            15.0.19205.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)             10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML                                     3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                            4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                    10.0.19041
```

**Summary**
I want to know if there's a way to visually add things like default and other constraints visually to a DB being built via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Solutions which circumvent the problem are welcome (like SQL code to alter tables so that they include rules to enforce the defaults), but my main concert is visual design.

Comment: Are you asking how to do things in SSMS rather than using `ALTER TABLE` and other commands?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. It's not pretty but it works.

- Have the object explorer open (it's usually on the left - F8 brings it back if you removed it)
- On the tree, open your database, then the tables
- Right click on your table and select 'design'
- Most usual things (column name, type) can be done in the main window, but other things (like defaults, collations, IDENTITY) can be done in the panel below.

Below is my testing database.. On the left, I've opened the table 'Customers' in the Testdb. This opens the windows in the middle. At the top of that is the main area for defining columns e.g., name, datatype, allowing NULLs. Below that (column properties) you can add more options if desired.

For your specific question: default values go into the 'Default value or binding' area in the bottom section.

[image]

Note that if you want to add foreign keys, they're in the 'Keys' section on the left side (object explorer). Similarly for other constraints, triggers, etc.

Comment: Thank you! That's it. One last thing: Why do you think it says "default value or binding"? Is *binding* a synonym of generated value? I think the guys who develop SQL Server Management Studio are not in sync with the rest of Microsoft. While you get design modes as close as possible to the code, MS SQL Server Management Studio seems to be the exception. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: To be honest - I don't know. The [Microsoft documentation on default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) also just skips over that. I think they kinda leave SSMS the way it is (don't really change old features much, just add new ones) and focus instead on things like Azure Data Studio.

Comment: MS has to learn to accept that some people are not going to like some products. (I feel silly saying that about the company who forced DOS then Windows down humanity's throat, but I think it's time they grow away from that. People who dev for MS must bet on their own new favorite thing not being MS' next project to get canned. I'm a fan of MS because of one thing: standardization (even if forced. some even call it a monopoly... Having a common exchange is a good thing when taken seriously for the good reasons. The bad reasons happen when they just want to push something like Azure).

Comment: @Davi, when you specify a value for "Default Value or Binding", SSMS creates a default constraint for the column. You can see the DDL by clicking on the Table Designer menu and selecting Generate Change Script. The script will include DDL like `ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Customers_CustomerID DEFAULT (0) FOR CustomerID`

Comment: If you want to design tables and relationships totally visually, you can use Database Diagrams (expand DB, right click on Database Diagrams select new diagram). You can then add existing or new tables to the diagram, add primary keys and foreign key relationships. To add default values you need to modify the custom view so that you can default values within the diagram.